# How to ensure TLS1.3 in gRPC in c++

Tags: c++, ssl, grpc, tls1.3

If I am using TLS in gRPC how can I force the use of TLS1.3? I am using c++.

I have TLS working but if there a way to enforce a specific TLS version?

Comment: Hi, not sure if any of the [tls credentials](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/tls__credentials__options_8h.html) might be of help. (Go has a different way it looks like https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/1917)

Comment: Thanks for that. It doesn't seem like anything on the TLS credentials link does quite what I'm after. From digging around online it doesn't appear to be possible unfortunately. Do you know what version of TLS is used by the c++ version of gRPC by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gRPC uses TLS1.3 in c++ by default, this is true as of gRPC version 1.32.0 anyway. This has been verified with wireshark.